# Homemorphism V: $P^2\mathbb{R} \rightarrow w(S^2)$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I was reading this question: [Condition for a homeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4059312/condition-for-a-homeomorphism) and I got some doubt.

As $w(S^2)$ consists of the antipodal points, therefore any map constructed from $P^2\mathbb{R}$ to $w(S^2)$ is injective and continuous, as $P^2\mathbb{R}$ is a compact I conclude that V is an homeomorphism.

Is this argument enough or I have to prove something else?

Thank you very much!